# How to create an animation with the "svgwrite" library in python

Tags: python, animation, svg

I'm working on the creation of a bioinformatic tool using the library SVGWRITE.

I need some help with the using of the animate module, (like animateColor, animateMotion...), because even if I read the documentation, also read all the example in the svgwrite package, I couldn't find a way to have some informations about how to properly use it.

The SVG draw I'm creating is composed only with rectangles, what I call exon, this is how I'm creating them :

```
def drawExon(dwg,lineNumber,start,end,rvb):

""" 
A function which draw a new exon on a opened dwg draw 
it draw that exon from 'start', to 'end' (x position)
at the line 'lineNumber' (y position) with the color'rvb' 
"""

  dwg.add(dwg.rect((start,lineNumber*line_height),(end - start, 
  exon_height),fill=svgwrite.rgb(rvb[0],rvb[1],rvb[2])))
```

I would like to add a animation of theses rectangles, when I fly over the rectangle, I would like that an ID appear on that rectangle (in a text box above it) and also that the rectangle could change color.

The problem is that I have no idea of how and where to apply the animate module, neither what kind of arguments I have to give...

Well, I tried during the last two hours to do such a thing, I read many things on the following link:
http://svgwrite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/classes/animate.html#animate

But it didn't help me to find a answer.

Comment: Look, I found this ... https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69338/generating-svg-animation-of-falling-leaves good luck

Answer (score 2):

Heres an example for rotating rectangle and color changing text

```
import svgwrite 

path = [(100,100),(100,200),(200,200),(200,100)]

image = svgwrite.Drawing('test.svg',size=(300,300))

rectangle = image.add(image.polygon(path,id ='polygon',stroke="black",fill="white"))
rectangle.add(image.animateTransform("rotate","transform",id="polygon", from_="0 150 150", to="360 150 150",dur="4s",begin="0s",repeatCount="indefinite"))
text = image.add(image.text('rectangle1',insert=(150,30),id="text"))
text.add(image.animateColor("fill", attributeType="XML",from_="green", to="red",id="text", dur="4s",repeatCount="indefinite"))

image.save()
```

notice that animateColor dont work in every browsers